# If Exists Dont Add Data Entity Framework Many-To-Many

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, one-to-many

I have these two `Models` the logic is here One Post can have multiple Categories.

```
     public class Post
     {
            public Post()
            {
                this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
            }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
            public string PostImage { get; set; }
            public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime? PublishedDate { get; set; }
            public string  CreatedBy { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

      }

     public class Category
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        }
```

I have three static categories.

When I am trying to add new post its multiplexing `CategoryTable` creating new categories with same name ,And Mapping Them in to `CategoryPostsTable`.

The problem is here i want to map that data with existing categories. I dont want to add new category with same name.

I am using Repository Pattern how should i control that ? Is EF has some solution for that  ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have code like:

```
var post = new Post();
post.Categories.Add(cat);
context.Posts.Add(post);
```

...where `cat` is a `Category` object representing an existing category.

The latter `Add` method (`DbSet.Add`) doesn't only mark the received entity as `Added` but all entities in its object graph *that are not attached to the context*. So `cat` will also be marked as `Added` if it wasn't attached yet.

What you can do is

```
context.Entry(cat).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Now EF will only create the association to the category, but not insert a new category.